# ¿Cómo conseguir esta forma con CSS para incluir en un selector :after?

Tags: css, css3

**SOLUCIONADO:**

```css
content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -13px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-left: 7px solid #4A4A49;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #4A4A49;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);
```

(Mi problema era que estaba manteniendo el background-color y por eso no veia que hacia la forma de L, lo veia todo relleno.)

¿Cómo puedo conseguir hacer esa forma de `L` con *CSS* para incluir dentro de un `selector :after`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mismo tengo este código:

```css
h1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1><center>Prueba</center></h1>
```

Comment: No pongas una edición "solucionado" con el código de la solución; Añade una respuesta con la solución que encontraste y acéptala. Y si era un fallo tipográfico o algo que realmente no va a ayudar a usuarios futuros, quizás lo que quieras es borrar la pregunta directamente

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacerlo fácilmente con el atributo **border**:

```css
.ele {
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
 <div class="ele">
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No me funciona. Ahora mismo la forma que tengo puesta es como un subrayado, es decir una simple linea:

h2:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: #111;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-50px, 0px, 0px);
}

Me gustaría convertir eso en la forma que comento arriba, pero con tu codigo no me funciona. Gracias.

Comment: Me temo que hasta el momento tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, para recibir una respuesta más concreta deberías añadir la estructura `html`donde utilizas ese título y qué estilos le afectan antes de que utilices el selector `:after`

Comment: He editado el post con el css que afecta al h2

Answer (score 0):

Con lo que dice nuestro compañero @Hechi funcionaria. Solo agregale un content y el ::after

```
h2::after { 
    content: "CONTENIDO DE ALGO";
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```